# New plywood subfloor under new engineered floor. How to level one section?

Tags: flooring, engineered-flooring

Is a 12 x 16 bedroom. There's a section at the door that isn't level. A dip of about 3/16" over a 4' run just by the door.  I plan on removing and replacing that 4'x4' section in order to make it level. The question is what to put beneath it where it dips to support it. Leveling compound? Tar paper?

There is plywood below the particleboard section that I'll remove. Would self-leveling compound be appropriate? I'm concerned that it'll be brittle and crack/shift over time.

Comment: Do you know why there's a dip. A little more info will help get you a good answer.

Comment: I may know more after I take up that section of particleboard. The basement is finished so I can't see from underneath.

Comment: "I plan on removing and replacing that 4'x4' section" of subfloor? You'll have a heck of a time getting self-leveling compound to balance on the floor joists while you install the plywood back on top. You'd put the SLC on _top_ of the subfloor. Or, lift the subfloor and shim the top of the joists level, then reinstall the fubfloor.

Comment: There is plywood below the particleboard section that I'll remove. Would self-leveling compound be appropriate? Im concerned that it'll be brittle and crack/shift over time.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a self leveling cementitious product or build it up with a cork underlayment or both. I've done many rehabs using this method

Comment: Cork seems like a padding or underlayment level that many engineered floors do _not_ approve of installing. This may not be appropriate for all installations.

Comment: The "leveling" will be done between the base plywood and the added plywood (that replaces the non-flat particleboard. The engineered floor will be atop all that.

Answer (score 1):

Leveling products can be messy and troublesome, especially if your subfloor isn't level. They can also disintegrate over time due to movement. I generally don't use them except over concrete.

In my opinion **the subfloor should be level, not just the underlayment**. I would be opening that up and shimming or sistering the framing. If you can't cut tight to the wall, *there* is where you could use some compound to fill, using a straightedge off the raised subfloor.

Post photos for more detailed suggestions.